# Is there a way of turning WIFI on/off in flutter [Android]?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, wifi

I want to turn WIFI on/off in a click of a button with Flutter.

I tried **IOT** package but it did nothing...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check [system_shortcuts](https://pub.dev/packages/system_shortcuts) plugin.

> await SystemShortcuts.wifi();// toggle wifi in android

It seems, from the documentation, that the plugin can only toggle WiFi on devices running on Android.